# 0MQ ROUTER DEALER paradigm not working in Docker container

Tags: java, docker, zeromq

Trying to use the 0MQ ROUTER DEALER paradigm to communicate and get work done between multiple clients and services.

The client, broker and server run in their respective Docker containers 
If i run the client, broker, worker as standalone Java programs instead of Docker containers, everything works OK.

The cient connects to ROUTER port and sends message however does not get response from broker.

The broker binds to the ROUTER and DEALER port but is not able to process any message.

The worker connects to the DEALER port but is not getting any work assigned.

Following is client snippet

```
        reqSocket = context.socket(SocketType.REQ);
        String reqStr = "tcp://a.b.c.d:" + config.getRouterPort();
        boolean ret = reqSocket.connect(reqStr);
        String json;
        json = objMap.writeValueAsString(req);
        ret = reqSocket.send(json.getBytes(), 0);
        byte[] recv = reqSocket.recv();
```

Following is broker snippet

```
    routerSocket = context.socket(SocketType.ROUTER);
    String routerString = "tcp://*:" + config.getRouterPort();
    boolean ret = routerSocket.bind(routerString);

    dealerSocket = context.socket(SocketType.DEALER);
    String dealerString = "tcp://*:" + config.getDealerPort();
    ret = dealerSocket.bind(dealerString);

    ZMQ.proxy(routerSocket, dealerSocket, null);
```

Following is worker snippet

```
        listener = context.socket(SocketType.REP);
        String dealerStr = "tcp://a.b.c.d:" + config.getDealerPort();
        boolean ret = listener.connect(dealerStr);
        while (true) {
            byte[] msg = listener.recv(0);
            boolean ret = listener.send(objMap.writeValueAsBytes(processMessage(msg)), 0);
        }
```

any help in resolving this or any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this has been fixed now by making the broker container expose both the DEALER and ROUTER ports and map them to ports on host machine.